# Cannot bind a SelectedValue to a combobox for WPF in xaml from property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am not understanding the binding principle error I am getting so I was curious: 'A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'CurrentUser' of type 'Demo.ViewModel.MainWindowViewModel'.'  My xaml is binding correctly EXCEPT for selected a default value for the combobox, 'SelectedValue'.   Now this attribute will be fine if I do it manually with a 'SelectedValue = "1"' but not with code.  The end goal is I want to generate a list of people and their identity seed from a database and this works fine.  But I also want to use the Windows login to then set an auto default for the user.  This would work if the property would work but I am guessing there is more I need to know on binding rules.  Sort of like the WPF bindings only work with certain types and rules.  I could trick it and make the 'Person' class have the defaultuser and then reference that but it seems that it should be it's own property to be well defined and I was hoping someone that was better at WPF binding would know my issue.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Height="30" Width="170" Margin="10" x:Name="combopersons" 
                    FontSize="20"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=People}"
                    DisplayMemberPath="FirstName"
                    SelectedValuePath="PersonId" 
                    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentUser}" />
```

partial C# code behind for viewmodel code:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<Person> _people;
string _curuser;

public string CurrentUser 
        { 
            get
            {
                if (_curuser == null)
                {
                    _curuser = "1";
                }
                return _curuser;
            } 

        }

public ReadOnlyCollection<Person> People 
        {
            get
            {
                if(_people == null)
                {
                    List<Person> persns = this.GetPeople();
                    _people = new ReadOnlyCollection<Person>(persns);
                }
                return _people;
            }
        }

        List<Person> GetPeople()
        {
            ExpensesEntities ee = new ExpensesEntities();
            return ee.tePersons.Select(x => new Person
                                         {
                                             PersonId = x.PersonID,
                                             FirstName = x.FirstName
                                         }).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: is `PersonID` string or int? and since you don't have a setter on `CurrentUser` you may want to set your `BindingMode` to `OneWay`

Comment: That is an acceptable method, however I want to be able to change the value of the combobox later.  I did not test this but I assume I would want to set my property as well as get it.  This fixed the issue in the method I would like for my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selected value is a [two way binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode.aspx), meaning that the bound property is **read** to change the selected value, but if the selection is changed because the user uses the combobox, the property is **set** to that value.

So there are two solutions:

- Make the binding one way: `SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentUser, Mode=OneWay}"`
- Create a setter on the read only property, and properly handle the value changes of the user.

The right choice depends on your application.

Comment: That is all it was, I forgot to add a set on my property.  When you mentioned two way and the property of the combobox could be changed I did a little bit of a facepalm.  No I want it to be able to be changed in my app. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forget define set method in CurrentUser property?
Other thing - your class shall implemented IPropertyNotify interface, but it is not cause for the error.